# How can I change color of TextField border? iOS

Tags: text, ios7

I can use clear body style in inspector and when I can draw custom lines, but may be there is a more simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor]CGColor];
textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
```

also add its frameworks^